# Making a cross domain ajax request to a linkedIn api endpoint

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

I am trying to get the sharecount on a website's articles by making a `GET` request to a linkedIn api endpoint:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=http://stylehatch.co&format=json
```

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=http://stylehatch.co&format=json',
    type: 'GET',
    processData: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json",
    jsonp: false,
    success: function(data) { alert('succeeded'); },
    error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
});
```

When I run it, I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=http://stylehatch.co&format=json. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://aranca.craft.dev' is therefore not allowed access.`
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I access the sharedcount data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `dataType: 'jsonp'` to resolve this `CORS` issue like:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=http://stylehatch.co',
  type: 'GET',
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('Count: ' + data.count);
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log('Failed!');
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```